# Android Is it a good practice to use LocationListener in a IntentService?

Tags: android, intentservice, locationlistener

My app has a widget and shows information depending on the location of the device.

I would like to get the location by using a IntentService, because it destroys itself after the job is done, however the algorythm executes the

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
```

method and finishes. so there is no time to listen for some locations and give the info back.

is it possible to let the LocationListener wait until the

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
```

is called?

how to use properly the Looper in the

```
LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
```

method?

here the entire code for the IntentService:

```
public class GetLocation extends IntentService {
public GetLocation() {
    super("GetLocation");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private static final String TAG = "GetLocation";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;
private ResultReceiver resultReceiver;
public static final String RECEIVER = "receiver";
public static final String GPS = "gps";
private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
public static String RESULT = "result";
Location mLastLocation;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {

    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
        result = Activity.RESULT_OK;
        publishResults(new double[] { mLastLocation.getLatitude(),
                mLastLocation.getLongitude() }, result);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
//          new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) };

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e(TAG, "onHandleIntent");
    resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);

    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }


}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                Log.i(TAG, "remove location listners");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}

private void publishResults(double[] gps, int result) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putDoubleArray(GPS, gps);
    bundle.putInt(RESULT, result);
    resultReceiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
}
}
```

EDIT:

I would like to add the final code for the Service that gives the coordinates to a receiver:

However, it is only the gps provider working, the network is ignored on the device (everything is activated in the settings)

```
public class LocationGetter extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "LocationGetter";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;
private ResultReceiver resultReceiver;
public static final String RECEIVER = "receiver";
public static final String GPS = "gps";
private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
public static String RESULT = "result";
Location mLastLocation;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);

    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {

    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
        result = Activity.RESULT_OK;
        publishResults(new double[] { mLastLocation.getLatitude(),
                mLastLocation.getLongitude() }, result);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) };

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}

private void publishResults(double[] gps, int result) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putDoubleArray(GPS, gps);
    bundle.putInt(RESULT, result);
    resultReceiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
}
}
```

Comment: "I would like to get the location by using a IntentService, because it destroys itself after the job is done" -- do this yourself in a regular `Service` by calling `stopSelf()` when your `Service` has received its location. IMHO, an `IntentService` is not a good solution for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had select the wrong way to go - you should use Service to listen for Location updates, because Service will not be closed after it's code have been executed.

Another way - is to subscribe some service component to Location updates via AndroidManifest.xml by defining proper IntentFilter. In this situation - it can be an IntentService, as only it's OnReceive() method will be executed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The 2nd method consumes more battery? Since I would like to update only every 30min?

Comment: Generally - yes. it will fire your service on every update.

But you can setup it 'disabled' and in your code you can use PackageManager to enable it when needed.

Comment: thank you but I will try it first with the Service (1st method). I updated the answer, it seems that only gps provider is triggering onLocationChanged ....